# JQuery background color change not showing immediately in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

In the following code, on Chrome, the background color change does not show until after the confirm is answered:

```
$('#ac_row_'+ac_table_row).children('td').css('background-color','#ffc3c3');
var agree=confirm( "Are you sure you want to delete this aircraft?" );
```

In Firefox and I.E. the color changes immediately and shows under the confirm modal dialog box.  How do I get the background color to update immediately on Chrome?

I found some similar questions, but they didn't seem to apply to my situation.  In those cases the color change never happens at all on Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I can think of right now is deferring the confirm call;

```
$('#ac_row_'+ac_table_row).children('td').css('background-color','#ffc3c3');
var agree;
setTimeout(function() {
    agree=confirm( "Are you sure you want to delete this aircraft?" );
});
```

But then you have to wait the timeout to check for agree's value.

Comment: I tried it with only a 50 millisecond timeout and it works. I put the check for agree's value and rest of the code that happens afterward inside the function.

Comment: I tried a timeout of 0, and also 1, but they didn't work. I'm guessing Chrome just needs a little time to update the background color before the modal confirm window pauses everything.  (25 ms works, but I think 50 is probably safer and the delay is hardly noticiable.)

Comment: In my case 0 ms delay is working fine. Which version are you working on?